# Why do I get traceback erros when using python on CMD?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

[**I dont really know what's happening here. I installed python 3.10.6 but I can seem to any python commands in windows cmd.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g81QX.png)

I was trying to install opencv for a project. But can seem to use pip or any other python commands. Need help. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like python is not installed or path is not set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first typed "python" you activated the interactive console.
To exit you can type "exit()". Then you can type "python -v"

Comment: Seems like this was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer, so your question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot i see that the issue is you are trying to run `python -V` or `pip` commands from the python shell which is incorrect, you supposed to run these commands directly without typing `python` first.